# Column dupe renaming in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, indexing

I have the following csv file of data:

```
id,number,id
132605,1,1
132750,2,1
```

Pandas currently renames this to:

```
       id number id.1
0  132605      1    1
1  132750      2    1
```

Is there a way to customize how this is renamed? For example, I would prefer:

```
           id number id2
0  132605      1    1
1  132750      2    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `rename`: use period delimiter

Assuming duplicate column labels are the *only* instances where a column name contains a period (`.`), you can use a custom function with [`pd.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
from io import StringIO

file = """id,number,id
132605,1,1
132750,2,1"""

def rename_func(x):
    if '.' not in x:
        return x
    name, num = x.split('.')
    return f'{name}{int(num)+1}'

# replace StringIO(file) with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file))\
       .rename(columns=rename_func)

print(df)

       id  number  id2
0  132605       1    1
1  132750       2    1
```

#### `csv.reader`: robust solution

A robust solution is possible with the `csv` module from the standard library:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

# replace StringIO(file) with open('file.csv', 'r')
with StringIO(file) as fin:
    headers = next(csv.reader(fin))

def rename_duplicates(original_cols):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    for x in original_cols:
        count[x] += 1
        yield f'{x}{count[x]}' if count[x] > 1 else x

df.columns = rename_duplicates(headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

No. You can't change the way suffix get added with `pandas` API.

**Long answer**

This is handled by `pandas.read_csv`'s `mangle_dupe_cols` option, which turning it off is currently not supported.

What you can do is to modify the source code of `pandas.io.parsers._maybe_dedup_names`, but as always, it is not very much recommended.

```
def _maybe_dedup_names(self, names):
    if self.mangle_dupe_cols:
        names = list(names)  
        # counts = defaultdict(int)
        counts = defaultdict(lambda:1) 
        # So that your duplicated column suffix starts with 2 not 1
        is_potential_mi = _is_potential_multi_index(names)

        for i, col in enumerate(names):
            cur_count = counts[col]

            while cur_count > 0:
                counts[col] = cur_count + 1

                if is_potential_mi:
                    # col = col[:-1] + ('%s.%d' % (col[-1], cur_count),)
                    col = col[:-1] + ('%s%d' % (col[-1], cur_count),)
                else:
                    # col = '%s.%d' % (col, cur_count)
                    col = '%s%d' % (col, cur_count)
                # eliminate '.' from formating
                cur_count = counts[col]

            names[i] = col
            counts[col] = cur_count + 1
```