# Loading a dataframe with multiple fields with the same name

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data, which comes from an excel file:

```
L = [{'id': [1,2,3]},
     {'name': [4,3,2]},
     {'id': [9,0,1]}]
```

How would I load this into a dataframe so that my result looks like:

```
   id  name  id
0   9     4  1
1   0     3  2
2   1     2  3
```

Doing something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([(k, v) for d in L for k, v in d.items()]))
```

Chops off one of the columns as the dicts don't support dupe key names.

Comment: Ya can't have duplicate column names.

Comment: @W-B note the duplicate column names now.

Comment: @W-B oh I see -- thanks for pointing that out: I didn't see that answer yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [531]: df = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, L), axis=1); df
Out[531]: 
   id  name  id
0   1     4   9
1   2     3   0
2   3     2   1
```

You might also want to consider disambiguating the columns:

```
In [551]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.columns).cumcount().astype(str)]).map('_'.join)

In [552]: df
Out[552]: 
   id_0  name_0  id_1
0     1       4     9
1     2       3     0
2     3       2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate an iterable of Pandas series objects:

```
df = pd.concat((pd.Series(v, name=k) for d in L for k, v in d.items()), axis=1)

print(df)

   id  name  id
0   1     4   9
1   2     3   0
2   3     2   1
```

This should be cheaper than concatenating dataframes:

```
L *= 10**3

%timeit pd.concat((pd.Series(v, name=k) for d in L for k, v in d.items()), axis=1)  # 480 ms
%timeit pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, L), axis=1)                                     # 1.25 s
```

To rename columns to distinguish your duplicate column labels, you can use [this renaming recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53939093/9209546) from your previous question:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def rename_duplicates(original_cols):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    for x in original_cols:
        yield f'{x}_{count[x]}'
        count[x] += 1

df.columns = rename_duplicates(df.columns)

print(df)

   id_0  name_0  id_1
0     1       4     9
1     2       3     0
2     3       2     1
```